# Multi table queries using Azure Mobile Services and android

Tags: android, azure

I am testing out the Azure Mobile Services facility with an Android App. For single table CRUD operations it works very well, but I have been unable to find any documentation or examples on multi-table queries.  Has anyone seen anything on this front - either for doing something server side (say creating views) or on the android device?

thanks

anton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is supported, but to create a view and have access to it through mobile services you would first need to create the object as a table from the Azure portal, then use sp_rename in the database to rename your table [servicename].[tablename] to [servicename].[tablename2], and finally create a view called [servicename].[tablename]. I tested this and it seems to work. This is how to change the ToDoItem table into a view from the sample program provided by Microsoft:

sp_rename [enzotest.todoitem], [todoitem2]

CREATE VIEW enzotest.todoitem
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT id, [text], complete FROM enzotest.todoitem2

You do not need to have SCHEMABINDING in place, but it helps manage the object from the portal. Now that you have a view, you should be able to easily join to other tables.

Comment: i think it's not good idea when data is too much or we can not map with complex object if we can plz give me some link or tutorial ..thx

Comment: @SanjayPatel did you fixed your issue.  please provide steps how did you resolved that issue